# Interpolated lines with varying colors - drawing order of objects is wrong (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, line, style

I'm using Interpolated Lines styling with Varying Width and Varying Colors, everything looks neat, but the drawing order of lines is random, so the the thinner and lighter colored lines show on top of the wider dark line.

How I want the result:

[image]

How it comes out:

[image]

You can see the line ends on top of the darker line. Is there a workaround or a way to make it less noticable? Am using QGIS 3.30.1 if that's any help. Also the Layer Styling settings are here:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can tick the box for

```
Control feature rendering order
```

and set the rendering order based on your `Rank`

It is visible right at the bottom of your screenshot of the layer styling panel.